# When a football match goes to extra time, when is full time?

Tags: football, terminology

The events in a hypothetical football match are:

- 45 mins - half-time (score 1-1)

  90 mins - end of normal time (score 2-2)

  120 mins - after extra time (score 3-2)

Would it be correct to say that score was 2-2 at full-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the following statements would be correct:

- The score was 2-2 at full time **OR** The score was 2-2 at the end of regulation time
- The score was 3-2 at the end of extra time

Here is a quote from a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtime_(sports)#Association_football_(soccer)) for terms used to describe overtime in sports:

> In association football knock-out competitions or competition stages, teams play an extra 30 minutes, called extra time, when the deciding leg (or replay of a tie) has not produced a winner by the end of regulation or full-time.

Now of course, there are plently of different valid ways of referring to the score at either the end of regulation or extra time and there isn't a single correct way, but at least with these terms people will probably know what you are talking about and not be confused.

Comment: This answer doesn't bring in any additional information to the previous answer. It's always good to read other answers, before posting yours.

Comment: @gdrt I wrote this answer because it is more concice and goes straight to the point by directly answering with a yes/no, as I thought he simply wanted to know the right way of specifying the score at the end of a game without confusing people when talking about football.

Comment: Sorry, but to me it's just a copy-paste of the previous answer. Besides that, downvoting other answers (which have the same content as yours) just to promote yours is not what we usually do in this community.

Comment: @gdrt Sorry about that mate you are right, but regarding the answer I still believe that mine isn't a copy/paste of yours and that it directly answers his question more clearly by telling him what he can say in an explicit way.

Answer (score 4):

There's no reference to specific term to be used in the [Laws of the Game](http://www.theifab.com/laws), especially in the *Law 7: the Duration of the Match*. Your best bet would be to refer to the rules/regulations of the particular tournament that you're interested in, but again it's unlikely that any tournament rules would include such terminology definitions.

**Answering your question, I would say yes.** By *"full-time"* people usually mean the score at the end of 90 minutes but it adds some ambiguity, so the terms *"regulation time"* or *"the end of regulation time"* are more preferred. Here's the [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtime_(sports)#Association_football_(soccer)) article explaining respective terms.

To refer to the end of 120 minutes, people use *"after extra time" (a.e.t.)*. Here's an example from [UEFA Champions League 2013/14 Final match report](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2014/matches/round=2000483/match=2011883/index.html#/iv/history/match/2011883).

To refer to the end of game after 120 minutes and penalty shootouts, people use *"after penalties"* or *"on penalties"*. Here's an example from [UEFA Champions League 2015/16 Final match report](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2016/matches/round=2000638/match=2015789/index.html#/iv/history/match/2015789).

But again, there's no central repository which stores respective definitions of minor football terms. In Russian, for instance, to refer to the end of 90 minutes people mostly use *"в конце основного времени"* which means *"at the end of main time"*, so what I'm saying is such non-regulated terms can have many different forms.